# Error connecting to MySQL server using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I get a **Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll** error when trying to connect to my server in C#.

I've made a MySQL server using [gearhost](https://my.gearhost.com/CloudSite). Now I'm trying to test my connection using C# in WindowsForms. Here's my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=den1.mysql6.gear.host;" +
            "Database=databasetestroy;" +
            "Uid=databasetestroy;" +
            "Pwd=myPassHere");

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2P1p.jpg) a screenshot of my server/account details that I use to login.
I've succesfully logged in on the server from MySQL workbench.

Why do I get an error when trying to login?

I didn't add the details because they were in Dutch, I need to fix that so I can get the errors in English. 
The solution of Tim Jarvis solved everything, I didn't know that the 'standard' SQL class was only meant for Microsoft. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You've not provided the details of that exception. Without the details, we can't help. Please see [ask], and then come back and [edit] your question to provide the relevant details of the error. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL is a completely different RDBMS from Microsoft SQL Server.  Figure out which one you are using and use the correct DB Provider library.  Meanwhile read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to connect using the MSSQLServer database client, to connect to MySql you will need to use the MySql Client

```
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient
....
var myConnection = new MySqlConnection(..etc..)
```

You can get the client via Nuget (supplied by Oracle)